vite server watch doesn't work without usePolling=true
I'm doing some dev with Vue3& Vite using VisualCode on MacOS.
However, I can not make the watcher work without usePolling: true.
Meaning that without usePolling: true, my watcher does not work at wall. I'm sure it's a config issue, but really don't know which one. Either Vcode or Vite.config
This uses a lot of CPU because it's a big project. I read about WSL, but doesn't apply being already on mac.
My vite.config is this:
export default defineConfig(({mode}) => {
  // const mode = mode?.NODE_ENV || 'development';
  // console.log("Current mode:", mode);
  // const env = dotenv.config({ path: `./.env.${mode}` }).parsed;
  return {
    plugins: [vue()],
    debug: true,
    define: {
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@src':  path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), // Adjust the path accordingly
      },
    },
    build: {
      target: 'es2015',
      outDir: 'dist',
      envFile: true
    },
    server: {
      hmr: { overlay: true }, // Disable HMR overlay
      watch: {
        ignored: ['!**/dist/'],
        usePolling: false
      }
    },
  }
});

I'm new to this modern front-end development, coming from a backend experience, so I don't know where to pick this up.

Wait, why do you even need polling? If you run a web server (with npm run dev or whatever), you gonna have a watcher for your file already. Triggering an HMR (Hot Module Reload) update of your UI. This is out of the box of any project created with the Vue CLI for quite some time. Is this what you used to create your project and start your server? https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application

@kissu I'm using polling because that's the only way it works (listens to files changes). Yes I've used that for project/server setup. But still, for some reason, without polling my files don't get watched.
I've also checked Window logs within visualcode... no error I could relate to.

You should not need to tinker with those settings, something is wrong with your setup aside from the config shown here. So, you use VScode on Windows that's right? I am not sure about the logs you're talking about but is there a way for you to launch the server in a WSL2 terminal and run an npm run dev? You should see: "Vite is warmed up" and then see some "hmr update [file name]" popping in the terminal on any change. Feel free to maybe post some images to show a bit of your setup and what you see in the terminal or your VScode, might help a lot.

no, I'm using it on MacOS, that's why WSL doesn't apply to MacOS.  I see the HMR update, but only when using polling true. Otherwise nothing.

Oh wait yes you're on MacOS. What do you mean by "I've also checked Window logs within visualcode" if you're on MacOS?! You should not use polling, because it's not efficient and will be quite annoying on bigger projects. Can you send some screenshots of your terminal/etc? Is it happening on a brand-new app? Do you have a somewhat latest Node version running? Maybe you have a GitHub repo to share? (to like double-check that it's not a project issue)

the Window (not windows) log file I mean from Developer: Open Log File in Visualcode.
I know that polling won't work for this as large project, that's why I try to fix it.
12:25:56 PM [vite] hmr update /src/views/account/fragments/Billing.vue, /src/assets/main.css (x28)
Previous is with polling
If I set it to false and restart, I only have this:
VITE v5.2.8  ready in 358 ms
➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
➜  Network: use --host to expose
➜  press h + enter to show help

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I still don't know what your setup is regarding all my previous comments, some screenshots are also welcome.

I have started a discussion, not sure how will show up on your side... https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257645/discussion-between-alexandru-r-and-kissu

Keep us updated when you find out what it is because it's quite interesting of an error!

File polling is required when you share files between the Windows host and WSL because WSL doesn't yet propagate the filesystem events. In other words, the content is copied, but there is no event to say "file X has been updated." These filesystem events are what most file watchers use because they are incredibly efficient.
Since that isn't an option, you have two options:

Revert to use polling, which brings along the CPU tax you're seeing
Keep your files only within the WSL environment. Files changed within WSL do trigger the expected filesystem events.

You can follow along with the discussion on this GitHub issue.
